# Content not updating at CloudFront and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, mern

We have deployed our system at AWS S3 Bucket. And we are using Amazon CloudFront to speed up the distribution of the content.

We are facing some strange issues. We have a system developed using MERN stack. We have deployed a build at S3 but the content at S3 is not being updated as per the new build. We have invalidated the distribution from CloudFront several times, but still it is loading the old content. But when we hard-refresh the page, it shows the updated content, but when we open the system again or when we refresh the browser, it again shows the old content. Means it only shows the updated content after hard-refresh, and for just one time.

For example, the new deployment's version number is 1.3, but S3 is showing content of build of previous version 1.2.

Any solution to sort it out will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it is caching in your own web browser? How did you access the content? You might want to test it using a different browser or by running `curl` from the command line.

Comment: Yes, it is caching in our own web browser. But even if I clear the caches and cookies, still the issue remains same. It displays updated content after hard refresh, but only once. And when I reload the page again, it again loads the previous content.
I test it on a system where that app has never loaded before, and it is working fine there.